# About a function and its Fourier transform being zero at the same time.

Tags: fourier-analysis

If we have $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. How can I prove that (if $f$ is not zero), $f$ and its Fourier transform $\cal{F}(f)$ can't be zero out of a bounded interval?

I think it involves the inversion formula, but how can we prove this in a rigurous way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322408/show-that-if-f-has-compact-support-then-its-fourier-transform-cannot-have-com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to go about this is the Paley-Wiener theorem:

> The Fourier transform of a distribution of compact support on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an entire function on $\mathbb{C}^n$

So, assume that both $f$ and $\widehat f$ are compactly supported. Then they are both compactly-supported entire functions (as, more or less, the Fourier transforms of each other). How many functions are both entire and compactly supported?

Take some point $x_0$ outside the support of $f$, and expand in a Taylor series there (possible because $f$ is entire). You know that $f$ and all of its derivatives are zero there, so what is the resulting Taylor series?

> the zero function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think you mean entire+compact support equales implies zero function. But I don't see exactly why...

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, I this is exactly what I mean. I gave some more exposition above.

Comment: Everything clear now. Thanks a lot, BaronVT!